# How can I scrape the sik description from this table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the sic description but I have not been successful. I have been trying to use requests and beautiful soup but I am coming nowhere near close.

https://sec.report/CIK/1418076

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get value of row 'SIC', you can use this example (also correct `User-Agent` needs to be specified):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://sec.report/CIK/1418076'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

print( soup.find('td', text="SIC").find_next('td').text )
```

Prints:

```
7129: Other Business Financing Companies Investors, Not Elsewhere Classified 6799
```

---

EDIT: Change the parser to `lxml` for correct parsing of HTML document:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://sec.report/CIK/1002771'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'lxml')

print( soup.find('td', text="SIC").find_next('td').text )
```

Prints:

```
1121: Distillery Products Industry Pharmaceutical Preparations 2834
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me. Why do you need to use the user-agent? and how would i  know if you have to use that?

Comment: @JPWilson Well, it's all trial and error. But changing User-Agent is first thing I do when I get incorrect response from server (some sites require other HTTP headers to be set, cookies etc. - it's not something that's equal for all sites).

Comment: cheers mate, I dont need a solution as its the only one that didnt work but for https://sec.report/CIK/1002771 youll see that the table is slightly different with SIC coming first based on your code I cant see why this would affect the output but the code that comes out is "Manufacturing" I changed my code to take the -1 from the split instead of 0th element. But I was wondering why it doesnt work for this one as your code looks for sic? Just curious if you know why this is.

Comment: @JPWilson The code is ok, but the parser `html.parser` parses the document somewhat badly. Change it to `lxml`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 '}
r = requests.get('https://sec.report/CIK/1418076', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

sic = soup.select_one('.table:nth-child(5) tr~ tr+ tr td:nth-child(2)')
print(sic.text)
```

Output:

`7129: Other Business Financing Companies Investors, Not Elsewhere Classified 6799`